# PHP echo function is not working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to PHP and WordPress and currently in learning phase.I am trying to append the host name of in my WordPress site URL so that i can change the host name at any time and here is waht i am trying to do

```
<?php
   $site="siteurl";
   $home="home";
?>
```

this is what i am trying to do in my php page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="<?php echo get_cdn($site_cdn); ?>/wp-
content/themes/abc/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" 
type="text/css" />
```

here is  my `get_cdn()` function

```
function get_cdn($cdn_name){
 if ($cdn_name="home" || $cdn_name="siteurl"){
     return "http://id.cloudfront.net";
  }
  else{
     return $cdn_name;
  }
}
```

so what i am trying to do is if the pass in value to the function is either `home` or `siteurl`, it will return the URL of amazon cdn server so as per my understanding the above script should be like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="http://id.cloudfront.net/wp-
    content/themes/abc/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" 
    type="text/css" />
```

but this is coming as

```
http://localhost/wordpress/id.cloudfront.net/wp-content/themes/abc/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css
```

i am not sure why this is happening and any help/pointer in this regard will be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if($cdn_name == "home" || $cdn_name == "siteurl"){`

To match two values with eachother, use $a == $b.
Two "=" that is. In PHP, === will also match the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

what is `$site_cdn` parameter you are sending, check that first.

It looks like you are sending an empty parameter, so your `get_cdn` function returns an empty string, and your src attribute is like

```
src="/wp-content/themes/abc/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"
```

and since you didn't specify any host, html fetches the css from your localhost